# a tour taking in several pubs

Tags: gerunds, relative-clauses, present-participles

The following is the definition of "pub crawl" in an Oxford dictionary. I'd like to know whether "taking in" can be paraphrased as "that takes in."

> a tour **taking in** several pubs or bars, with one or more drinks at each.

Consider also the following:

> Fred Jones went on a trip **visiting** friends up in Bangor, Maine.

Can "visiting" be replaced by "that visited"?

If the boldfaced element in one sentence but not the other can be paraphrased by a relative clause, could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first example, you can use "that takes in".

For the second example, you could make make that substitution, but it doesn't sound quite right to me. It was Fred who was visiting his friends, not the trip.

If the sentence were
Fred Jones went on a trip that visited several towns near Bangor, Maine.
that would be more natural.

Comment: I am not at all clear why you said "Fred Jones went on a trip that visited several towns near Bangor, Maine" would be more natural. Can a trip visit several towns?

Comment: @Apollyon Check this ngram link: https://tinyurl.com/y4yvl4lm  or just go to Google ngram and search for "trip visits". Then click on the the date groupings at the bottom. You will see a lot of examples that don't apply, but numerous examples will show that it is used that way. It just sounds wrong to say that "the trip visits friends" when it's more logical to say that Fred visits friends.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Collocation is really puzzling sometimes. How does it sound to say "The trip visited several pubs in the area"?

Comment: That sounds alright to me. As the ngram link shows, "the trip visits" can be used with places, but it's a little less usual than "takes in", or "stops at".

Answer (score -1):

> a tour **taking** in several pubs or bars, with one or more drinks at each
>
> a tour **that takes** in several pubs or bars, with one or more drinks at each

The second sentence is possible as an alternative for the first one, since both of them means: considering more than one bar where one or more drinks are present/served.

> Fred Jones went on a trip **visiting** friends up in Bangor, Maine.

The above sentence means that Fred went to visit his friends in Bangor on his trip. However,

> Fred Jones went on a trip **that visited** friends up in Bangor, Maine.

As said by @JackO'Flaherty in his answer, *that visited* used after the noun trip would indicate as if the trip is going to visit your friends, not you.

You can use statements like:

> Fred Jones (undertook)/went on a trip **to visit** his friends up in Bangor, Maine.
>
> Fred Jones (undertook)/went on a trip **that included visiting** his friends up in Bangor, Maine.
>
> Fred Jones (undertook)/went on a trip **for visiting** his friends up in Bangor, Maine.